# Selenium C# 4.7.0 throws System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception when tried to use the chromedriver

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var d = new ChromeDriver();
        d.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
        TestContext.WriteLine("Opened successfully");
    }
}
```

Tried replacing the chrome with Firefox / Safari / Edge it works perfectly fine. But for Chrome alone it throws

Console output:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver' with working directory '/Users/testuser/Documents/SeleniumCSharp/DemoSelenium/DemoSelenium/bin/Debug/net6.0'. No such file or directory
```

Result message:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver' with working directory '/Users/testuser/Documents/SeleniumCSharp/DemoSelenium/DemoSelenium/bin/Debug/net6.0'. No such file or directory
```

Comment: ChromeDriver needs to be in `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver` and the user running the process which runs the test needs execute permissions on the file. Either the file doesn't exist, or the user doesn't have permissions to execute that file.

Comment: Thanks ! that was not the issue either. There was a chromedriver that got corrupted and was lying in that folder. Once I removed and re executed the script it was working fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to place chromedriver.exe where Selenium can "find" it. One way is to place chromedriver.exe in the same folder as your calling program. Another way is to call a ChromeDriver constructor which takes the path to chromedriver.exe as a parameter.